# Exploratory Factor Analysis for Big Data: Smaller Loading Threshold and Variance Accounted For?

Tags: sample-size, factor-analysis, large-data, exploratory-data-analysis

I saw several pieces of literature mentioned that the larger the sample size, the lower the threshold to be set for loadings to be considered significant, and the lower the variance accounted for. I am trying to conduct an EFA on a big dataset with a sample size of around 900,000 on 7 variables. I get 3 factors with an eigenvalue above 1. The cumulative common variance of the 3 factors accounted for only 26% the total variance (include both unique and common variance). I wonder if I should just conclude that the model to be unstable and there are no latent variables, or shall I give the result a second thought due to its large sample size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a situation where you don't care if the parameters are statistically significant.  If you have a sample of 900,000 then (spoiler) they are.

And the parameters that are assumed to be zero are also not statistically significant.

Factor analysis is an exploratory technique. You're trying to understand the structure in your data, and you're trying not to discard too much information, so don't worry about statistical significance.

However, one way think of it is in terms of information vs complexity. You've from 7 items (or factors) which explain 100% of the covariance, to three factors, which explain 26%. This is not good - you've got 42% of the factors you started with, and you've only got 26 % of the information.

Comment: Thank you! I like the simple comparison of the proportion of variables maintained and the proportion of variance accounted for.